# How to create alter table statement for a table?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have two databases one for production and another for staging.

Now I have made many changes in the staging database and I want to make the production the same structure as the testing without dropping any table or losing any data.

I want to find a way where I can create alter table from staging database and apply it on the production database. Note the tables have many columns so I don't want to have to do that manually..

Comment: There are some tools which do this, including Power Designer. You reverse engineer each database, and the tool creates scripts for converting one to another.

Comment: You should be tracking the schema changes you make so you can reproduce them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLyog trial](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) or [SQLyog Community edition](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/), with this tool you be able to apply the changes to the production database using Schema and Data Synchronization feature.